# Is it a good practice to store different data in the same column - SQL

Tags: sql

I currently have a `Users` table which has the following columns:

1. UserId
2. Address

Currently we are storing the IP Address in the `Address` column. Moving forward, we need to store say a MAC address. Is it a good practice to store both of them in the same column (both are `varchar`) and have another column indicating what type it is `typeOfAddress int` with a 1 or 2 indicating type of address. Or should I create a separate nullable column (and change the existing one to nullable as well)

Comment: personally, I would create two separate columns, but your queries to get data will probably have the same number of clauses either way (i.e. `WHERE MACAddress IS NOT NULL` OR `WHERE typeOfAddress = 'MAC'`)

Comment: Just follow the *Principle of Least Surprise*: if the column is called `Address` - it should store an address - nothing else, nothing more, nothing less. Using a single column to store different types of data is just confusing and error-prone. Don't do it - what's the point? Use one column `MacAddress` and another `IPAddress` and everything is clear - for you and for anyone else who needs to read, understand and fix the code later on ....

Comment: The correct answer here will depend on your queries. Either design is acceptable - as long as your queries are consistent. Importantly, which paradigm will make more sense to you and to the others who will have to access it? Which makes more sense to consuming application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommended is this structure:

1. UserId
2. AddressType
3. Address

because it is in 3rd NF.

The disadvantages of simply using multiple columns in a single table are these:

- The need to remember to "null-handle" whenever filtering on Address
- Over time, the paradigm may expand beyond sense as new address types are addded; but a conversion becomes too costly to contemplate.

An AddressType table should be added with a FK relationship to prevent accidental entry of AddressTypes that look valid, but aren't.

Best of all, theoretically, would be a separate table for each AddressType, linked on UserId to the user table; but that really does look like overkill for the problem as presented.

Answer (score 7):

No it isn't good practice. One of the first things I was told several decades ago was 'a computer field should not be used for more than one purpose'. Otherwise you have in principle no way of knowing what it means, unless you have another indicator field, which you may as well use for the other value type, and you are introducing the entirely unnecessary risk of misinterpretation.

Comment: I agree that it isn't good practice.  But giving a reason WHY other than "someone once said" would make a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely create a separate nullable column. It will make writing all your future SQL on this table much easier, and keep everything much more maintainable overall.

Answer (score 1):

Well, based on the information given, it depends.

Would a user have both an IP address and a MAC address? If they do, you would need to put these records in a separate table with a foreign key relationship to the user record.

What about retrieval? Do these values often need to be retrieved when retrieving data about a user? If they do, it may make sense to store them in the same table and avoid the table join each time.

I'd be inclined to have two separate columns, one for `IpAddress` and another for `MacAddress`. This way it is clear what data is in what column without the need to lookup against another column to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't think you're going to be adding a bunch more different types of addresses, my preference would be for having two columns. I think it's simpler conceptually and simpler to query. But if you think you're going to be adding more types of "addresses" (whatever that may be), having 5 or 6 different columns may not be ideal. In that case, I'd go with one address column and one address_type column, and create a junction table that defines the address types.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making new columns, create a new table Address and AddressType, link to those:

```
Users
foreign key address_id

Address
id
value (varchar)
foreign key adress_type_id

AddressType
id
name (varchar)
```

Might be overkill, but it's good normalisation practice